# How to use Angular2 innerHTML expressions?

Tags: angular

I have:

```
<div [innerHtml]="myStr">
```

where:

```
this.myStr=='{{1+1}}'
```

I want it to display:

> 2

But it outputs:

> {{1+1}}

In Angular1 $compile was used for this issue. What do we use in Angular2 to compile expressions?

Comment: Why not directly put this.myStr = 1+1; ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960

Comment: i tried that link but it does not evaluate expressions in a string. It just dynamically creates components which are already defined but not yet instantiated.

Comment: '{{ 1+1 }}' is an extreme simplification of my use case but if I can get '{{ 1+1 }}' working then I think I'm all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ }}` (double brackets) signals angular to interpolate values on the `View`, or client, not in the component class. You just want to set the value of this.myStr like a normal string variable in javascript.

following your example, you would use

```
this.myStr = '' + (1 + 1);
```

or

```
this.myStr = (1 + 1).toString();
```

Comment: not really the answer i wanted but the best answer given so accepting it

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 template strings:

this.myStr=`${1+1}`

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings